# Best way to output strings based on conditionals logic

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, text

I am looking for opinions on how best to achieve the following. Its purpose is from the backend to get a bunch of user configured data, and then based on that data configure an object of texts which will be used on the frontend. I want frontend to be dumb and just know that it has to display `text.string`. Backend will contain the logic of determining what is shown.

I started with an object like this:

```
const someData = {
    hasBirthday: true,
    subscriptionFee: 100
}

const text = {
    welcome: (someData.hasBirthday) ? 'Happy birthday and welcome' : 'Welcome',
    cost: (someData.subscriptionFee > 0) ? `Your subscription fee is ${someData.subscriptionFee}` : `Enjoy your free stuff`
}
```

Fairly simple, however some additional logic was then introduced which was requiring nested ternary operators, so like this:

```
const someData = {
    hasBirthday: true,
    subscriptionFee: 100
}

const text = {
    welcome: (someData.hasBirthday) 
      ? 'Happy birthday and welcome' 
      : (someData.subscriptionFee > 0) 
        ? 'Welcome' 
        : 'Welcome, some custom message about your account being free',
    cost: (someData.subscriptionFee > 0) 
      ? `Your subscription fee is ${someData.subscriptionFee}` 
      : (someData.hasBirthday)
        ? `Enjoy your free stuff, you'll get a present on your birthday as well`
        : 'You only get free stuff, we do not know when your birthday is'
}
```

To note this is just a subset example, of course I could do `if else` statements, The text is pretty much irrelevant but there to serve a purpose that it is drastically different for each combination of data comparisons.

Now this got quite messy quite quickly, so I was wondering if anyone had thoughts on the following suggestion to keep things a little cleaner:

```
const texts = {
    welcome: [
        {
            comparator: (data) => data.hasBirthday,
            value: () => 'Happy birthday and welcome' 
        },
        {
            comparator: (data) => !data.hasBirthday && someData.subscriptionFee > 0,
            value: () => 'Welcome' 
        },
        {
            comparator: (data) => !data.hasBirthday && someData.subscriptionFee <= 0,
            value: () => 'Welcome, some custom message about your account being free'
        },       
        {
            comparator: (data) => true,
            value: () => 'This could act like an else conditional'
        },
    ],
    cost: [
        {
            comparator: (data) => data.subscriptionFee > 0,
            value: (data) => `Your subscription fee is ${data.subscriptionFee}` 
        },
        {
            comparator: (data) => data.subscriptionFee <= 0 && someData.hasBirthday,
            value: () => `Enjoy your free stuff, you'll get a present on your birthday as well` 
        },
        {
            comparator: (data) => data.subscriptionFee <= 0 && !someData.hasBirthday,
            value: () => 'You only get free stuff, we do not know when your birthday is'
        },
    ]
}

// using lodash
_.mapValues(texts, (text) => {
    const matched = _.find(text, (t) => t.comparator(someData));
    return (_.isFunction(_.get(matched, 'value'))) ? matched.value(someData) : null;
}),
```

So now each value has a comparator function which can have various logic to define if it should be shown. _.find will search recursively in order so we know that the first to last take precedence.

Anyway, looking for criticism on the above if anyone has any ideas. Thanks.

### Updated: Builder Pattern Implementation

I am not building another class instance, just returning an object, but still the same idea:

```
class Builder {
  constructor(data) {
    this._data = data;
  }

  setWelcome() { 
    if (this._data.hasBirthday) {
      this.welcome = 'Happy birthday and welcome'
    } else if (this._data.subscriptionFee > 0) {
      this.welcome = 'Welcome'
    } else {
      this.welcome = 'Welcome, some custom message about your account being free'
    }
    return this;
  }

  setCost () {
    if (this._data.subscriptionFee > 0) {
      this.cost = `Your subscription fee is ${this._data.subscriptionFee}`
    } else if (this._data.hasBirthday) {
      this.cost = `Enjoy your free stuff, you'll get a present on your birthday as well`
    } else {
      this.cost = 'You only get free stuff, we do not know when your birthday is'
    }
    return this;
  }

  create() {
    return _.omit(this
      .setWelcome()
      .setCost(), '_data')
  }
}

const object = new Builder({
  hasBirthday: true,
  subscriptionFee: 100
}).create();
```

Comment: Simple problem of builder pattern, just use builder pattern and return `this`. rather than this complex looking thing

Comment: What you are trying to do is very close to Server Side Rendering. I would use a template engine that supports SSR (e.g. [pugjs](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html))

Comment: @MehmetBaker - I would end up with many nested conditionals though? I am actually writing this logic because I am removing the client side rendering because it was quite messy

Comment: @xdeepakv - the builder pattern seems to handle conditionally adding properties to an object. That is not what I am doing, I will always have the same properties it is just the content of them that will change. Although using setters like the builder pattern shows could be a better method than the array.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you are looking for (hierarchical) *order* in the application of conditions. I would use arrays for that, so you can create your own hierarchy, apply conditions and subsequently return the first text found based on conditions, something like the given snippet. I suppose it's hard to circumvent complexity here, because it's not the code, but the number of conditions and the order you seem to want to apply.

But it may well be that I misunderstood what you mean.

```js
const someObjects = [
  {hasBirthday: true, subscriptionFee: 155, color: `brown`},
  {hasBirthday: false, subscriptionFee: 0, color: `orange`},
  {hasBirthday: false, subscriptionFee: 25, color: `green`, some: 'Hi there'},
]
someObjects.forEach(v => console.dir(getTexts(v)));

function getTexts(data) {
  const texts = {
    welcome: [
      [data => `${data.some}`, 
       data => data.some && data.some.startsWith("Hi")],
      ['Welcome', 
       data => !data.hasBirthday && data.subscriptionFee > 0],
      ['Happy birthday and welcome', 
       data => data.hasBirthday],
      ['Welcome, some custom message about your account being free', 
       data => !data.hasBirthday && data.subscriptionFee <= 0]
    ],
    cost: [
      [data => `Your subscription fee is $${data.subscriptionFee.toFixed(2)}`, 
       data => data.subscriptionFee > 0],
      [`Enjoy your free stuff, you'll get a present on your birthday as well`, 
       data => data.subscriptionFee <= 0 && data.hasBirthday],
      ['You only get free stuff, we do not know when your birthday is', 
       data => data.subscriptionFee <= 0 && !data.hasBirthday],
      ['Today, everything is free!', 
       data => !data.subscriptionFee]
    ],
    color: [
      [data => `Your color is ${data.color} (available on even dates)`, 
       data => [`orange`, `purple`].find( v => v === data.color) && 
        new Date().getDate() %2 !== 0],
      [data => `Your color ${data.color} is not available on odd dates`,
       data => [`orange`, `purple`].find( v => v === data.color) && 
        new Date().getDate() %2 === 0],
      [data => `Your color is ${data.color}`, 
       data => [`yellow`, `red`, `brown`, `blue`].find( v => v === data.color)],
      [data => `The color [${data.color || `no color given`}] is not available, sorry`, 
       data => !([`yellow`, `red`, `brown`, `blue`].find( v => v === data.color))],
    ]
  };
  const getStr = (str, data) => str instanceof Function ? str(data) : str;
  const txtReducer = txts => txts.reduce( (acc, [str, comparison]) => 
      comparison(data) && [...acc, getStr(str, data)] || acc, []);
  const textsReduced = Object.entries(texts).reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => 
      ({...acc, [key]: txtReducer(value)}), {});
  
  return Object.entries(textsReduced)
    .reduce( (acc, [key, texts]) => ({...acc, [key]: texts[0] }), {} );
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```